# best practice to design table schema and/or index for multiple composite index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this table:

```
id bigint primary key,
catx_1 varchar(3),
catx_2 varchar(3),
catx_3 varchar(3),
caty_1 varchar(3),
caty_2 varchar(3)
```

Let's say **(catx_1, catx_2, catx_3)** and **(caty_1, caty_2)** are "atomic", so when the table is lookup by **catx**, it should be done **from catx_1 then catx_2 and catx_3**, so do **caty**.

To be more clearly, the variation of where condition can be one of these:

```
#single catx
where catx_1 = x1
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2 and catx_3 = x3
#where catx_2 = x2 and catx_3 = x3 --> is impossible
#where catx_1 = x1 and catx_3 = x3 --> is impossible too

#single caty
where caty_1 = y1
where caty_1 = y1 and caty_2 = y2
#where caty_2 = y2 --> impossible

#mixed catx and caty
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2 and catx_3 = x3 and caty_1 = y1 and caty_2 = y2
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2                 and caty_1 = y1 and caty_2 = y2
where catx_1 = x1                                 and caty_1 = y1 and caty_2 = y2
where catx_1 = x1                                 and caty_1 = y1
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2 and catx_3 = x3 and caty_1 = y1
where catx_1 = x1 and catx_2 = x2                 and caty_1 = y1
where                                                 caty_1 = y1 and caty_2 = y2
where                                                 caty_1 = y1
#and so on..
```

My question is, how to create best index for above condition. I don't think creating index for each variation above is the right answer.
Sorry if my explanation is not good enough.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: They might just be sample names, but your column names suggest the table schema could be better designed. Perhaps as multiple tables. What are the columns storing?

Comment: If you can look into [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql). You can get better idea  credits @rickjames

Comment: @Schwern product code, customer code, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really looks like you have a table of multiple category paths. There are better ways to structure such a thing so that it...

- Is efficiently indexable
- Can support any number of categories
- Can support any length of category

---

First we need to collapse the pieces of a category into a single field. We can take advantage that `like 'foo%'` will use an index (`like '%foo%'` will not). Use a single field and store the categories with a delimiter like `x1/`, `x1/x2/`, `x1/x2/x3/`.

```
create table sample (
  id bigint primary key,
  cat1 varchar(10),
  cat2 varchar(10),
  index(cat1, cat2)
);
```

Now your searches become simple indexed `like`s.

```
-- Matches x1/ x1/x2/ x1/x2/x3/
where catx_1 like 'x1/%';

-- Matches x1/x2/ and x1/x3/
where catx_1 like 'x1/x2/%';

-- Matches x1/x2/x3/
where catx_1 like 'x1/x2/x3/%;
```

---

Whenever you have something like `col1`, `col2`, `col3` this suggests you instead need a 1-to-many join table to hold them. One thing has many categories.

```
create table things_categories (
  thing_id bigint not null,
  category varchar(255) not null,

  foreign key(thing_id) references things(id)
    on delete cascade,

  index(category, thing_id)
);

insert into things_categories (thing_id, category) values
  (1, "foo/bar/"),
  (1, "up/"),
  (1, "foo/"),
  (2, "this/that/whatever"),
  (3, "foo/"),
  (3, "left/right/");
```

Note that it's now a simple compound index on `category, thing_id`.

Then when you want to check if a thing matches multiple categories you do an inner [self join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp) on the table to assemble together rows with all combinations of a thing's categories.

```
-- inner self join to select all pairings of a thing's categories
select *
from things_categories tc1
inner join things_categories tc2
  on tc1.thing_id = tc2.thing_id
 and tc1.category != tc2.category;

tc1.thing_id tc1.category tc2.thing_id  tc2.category
1            foo/         1             foo/bar/
1            foo/         1             up/
3            foo/         3             left/right/
1            foo/bar/     1             up/
1            foo/bar/     1             foo/
3            left/right/  3             foo/
1            up/          1             foo/bar/
1            up/          1             foo/
```

And then you can filter on `t1.category` and `t2.category`.

```
select distinct tc1.thing_id
from things_categories tc1
inner join things_categories tc2
  on tc1.thing_id = tc2.thing_id
 and tc1.category != tc2.category
where tc2.category like 'left/%'
  and tc1.category like 'foo/%'

thing_id
3
```

If you want to do three categories, add another self-join.

---

Finally, use this as a [CTE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) and join with it to fetch information about the things.

```
with matching_things as (
  select distinct tc1.thing_id as thing_id
  from things_categories tc1
  inner join things_categories tc2
     on tc1.thing_id = tc2.thing_id
    and tc1.category != tc2.category
  where tc2.category like 'left/%'
    and tc1.category like 'foo/%'
)
select t.*
from things t
inner join matching_things mt on mt.thing_id = t.id

id    name
3     third
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f01e8834e1fd4e428c6acbb0f5bb7348)

This might seem a weird way to solve the problem, and it is, but this is how you do things in a relational database: with relationships.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that there is possibility only caty will be used. So if use single column method, I have to create 2 index, (catx,caty) and (caty). And if I have 3 category, I have to create indexes to cover all possibilty. Is that right?

Comment: @WilliamAnthony Yes, you'll have to set up your indexes like that. However, having multiple similar columns means you instead want a [one-to-many relationship](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561). That's a separate table with sample_id and category that you then join with `select * from sample join sample_categories on sample.id = sample_categories.sample_id`. Then you index sample_id, category.

Comment: did you mean like this: https://i.imgur.com/h9msplw.png I've done that before, but from the EXPLAIN result, it doesn't utilize the index well

Comment: @WilliamAnthony [Like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=612132fabadb387ba0c627b8e267b156). It's [emulating an `intersect`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/) which MySQL lacks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need three indexes:

1. `cat_x` index on (`catx_1` and `catx_2` and `catx_3`)
2. `cat_y` index on (`caty_1` and `caty_2`)
3. `cat_xy` index on (`catx_1` and `catx_2` and `catx_3` and `caty_1` and `caty_2`)

---

The `cat_x` index will likely be used when querying by (in the exact order):

1. `catx_1` only
2. `catx_1` and `catx_2`
3. `catx_1` and `catx_2` and `catx_3`

The `cat_y` index will likely be used when querying by (in the exact order):

1. `caty_1` only
2. `caty_1` and `caty_2`

Of course the optimizer may decide otherwise depending upon the data inside the table. Given the index fits inside the RAM, the query should be instantaneous.

Comment: one query can only use one index, cmiiw

Comment: Right one. Thanks.

Comment: Your catx is redindant because it is handled by catxy.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2)
(y1, y2, x1, x2)
```

handles nearly all of your cases.